# Codeigniter 4.0.4 redirecting to 404 - File Not Found

Tags: codeigniter

Why I got 404 - File Not Found when I run CI.

I am using xampp 8.0.0, I already put my CI folder to htdocs and also I've changed the config/app baseurl to http://localhost/framework-4.0.4/.

When I open it to browswer and click public it just redirected to 404.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uq6U.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a virtual host in your xampp for your project.

To do that for this codeigniter projects, open the the Apache httpd-vhosts.conf file which are located in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf, Added below lines of code at the end of the file.

using the example codeigniter-blog.local

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/framework-4.0.4/public"
ServerName codeigniter-blog.local
```

Now, Open the hosts file which are located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, Added below code into this file at the end.
127.0.0.1 codeigniter-blog.local

restart the xampp server.

If you open the browser and navigate http://codeigniter-blog.local, if you are getting welcome page, that means everything fine otherwise you'll get intl package is not enabled.

Comment: Thank you @marco I will try this later, when I get home.